# jquery Calendar plugin not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I decide to use this calendar plugin at my website

[Plugin](http://www.pigno.se/barn/PIGNOSE-Calendar/)

But it not works. 
I get this error

> $(...).pignoseCalendar is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (Index:97)
>       at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
>       at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)

But I include jquery plugin.

Here is my code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/pignose.calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/pignose.calendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;  margin-top: 85px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div id="left3" >

    </div>
    <div id="right3">
        <p class="blue-text" style="margin-top: 10px;"><b>Opening times</b></p>
        <div class="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.calendar').pignoseCalendar();
    });
</script>
```

Where can be error?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct path to your `pignose.calendar.min.js`?

Comment: Yes, I sure in correct path@N.Ivanov

Comment: Maybe you need to include the whole distribution? Check for any dependencies.

Comment: Trying. It's not Works@N.Ivanov

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache to refresh the javascript? Try and click Ctrl+F5 to hard refresh the page and see if that works

Comment: Yes, I was trying and it not works @N.Ivanov

Comment: hmm maybe change the jQuery version? Try with jQuery2 just to see if that is what causes the error, and 1 more suggestion would be to try and have your code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ //code goes here })` just to make sure that everything has loaded up before you call the `$.pignoseCalendar()` function.

Comment: @N.Ivanov looks like it already is within one of those.

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene have you checked the network tab to see if all the JS and CSS files are definitely loading successfully? If you watch the network as the page loads you can see the files being downloaded, and check if they all get a 200 OK status.

Comment: Yes , all are 200 status @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

You missed this one. We want add at first this js file in your header.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. You're probably calling jquery already and trying to use the full version js from pignose calendar.

Check if you have jQuery already and if so, stop using the full version and use the normal version. In case you use the normal version you'll have to add moment.js as well.
You can download it here: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

After that, call initialize like this:

```
$(function () {
      $('.pgcalendar').pignoseCalender();
})
```

It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to you including a 3.x version of Jquery, instead of a 1.x version that the pignose calendar requires.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also found including pignose calendar in the head rather than in the body helped it ensure it was loaded when needed. Though general practice is to heap as much script at the end of your page for faster load/render times.

Answer (score -1):

Download the pignose.calendar.full.js file

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Beautiful-Multifunctional-Calendar-Plugin-For-jQuery-PIGNOSE-Calender.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calender').pignoseCalendar();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calender').pignoseCalendar();
  })
</script>